# How to show different data to different users?

Tags: c#, sql, database

Lets say parents have logged into system, and I would like to show them only their children details in GridView control. Up to one child can be studying at the same school. How can I achieve that? I've tried to join 3 tables in my database and display into GridView like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP-H7KQUT1; Initial Catalog = SAOS; Integrated Security = True");

    String query = "SELECT s.FName FROM student s INNER JOIN student_parent sp ON s.SID = sp.SID INNER JOIN parent p ON sp.PID = p.PID WHERE p.PID = ";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    SqlDataReader dr;

    con.Open();

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = dr;

    GridView1.DataBind();

    con.Close();
}
```

I can display student details successfully but I don't know how to display different student details to different parents. I stuck at this line:

```
String query = "SELECT s.FName FROM student s INNER JOIN student_parent sp ON s.SID = sp.SID INNER JOIN parent p ON sp.PID = p.PID WHERE p.PID = ";
```

Any Advises & References are appreciated

Comment: With are the relationship between both tables?

Comment: @AntonioMiguelRomanGodinez many-to-many.  Table `student_parent` is junction table only stores `PID` & `SID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your schema, it looks like you've mostly got it: you need to get the parent id (pid) by looking at which user has logged into your web app.  Then you would use that information to most likely execute a query to lookup the pid.  Then you pass that as a parameter to your SQL statement in the form 'where p.pid=@PID'.  Here's some documentation on how to construct a query with parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2

Just one word of warning: be very careful about how you get and verify the parent id (i.e. don't just pass it in as a URL parameter, make sure it's something you authenticate and keep on the server side so it can't easily subject you to spoofing and injection attacks)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advise. But I'm still confused how to get PID & pass PID as parameter. pls help me with codes to gain better understanding